# "Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment" when editing cells in a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Aim is to create a shiny app to record data on the field. Observers record for each individual the species name, its sexe and its size (here restricted to 3 choices) via a selectinput or radioGroupButtons. An update button, create a dataframe of one line which is bind to a reactive table. The table is display on the app to check for potential entry mistake. This table is editable to allow observer to correct data directly into the table in case an error is spotted.

The problem is when the table is edited as soon as i update a new entry the edition dissapeared and the old value is back so i added an observeEvent to change the value in the dataframe. Unfortunately, i get : "Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment". If i replace the value by the exact same value it doesn't return the error but if i change it the error message appears for example replace a "M" by a "F" in the sexe column.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "sp", label = "sp", choices = c("espece1", "espece2")),
      radioGroupButtons(inputId = "sexe", label = "sexe", choices = c("M", "F"), status = "custom-class"),
      radioGroupButtons(inputId = "size", label = "size", choices = c("30", "20", "10"), status = "custom-class"),
      actionButton("update", "Update Table")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata <- reactiveVal(data.frame(sp = character(),
                                  sexe = character(),
                                  size = character(),
                                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    to_add <- data.frame(sp = input$sp,
                         sexe = input$sexe,
                         size = input$size)
    mydata(rbind(mydata(), to_add))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mydata(), editable = "cell",
              options = list(pageLength = 50,
                             paging = FALSE))
  })
 
observeEvent(input$table1_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$table1_cell_edit
    row <- info$row
    col <- info$col
    value <- info$value
 
    mydata()[row,col] <- value
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The following are some of my tries:

- add +1 at info$row and info$col even if rowname = TRUE i get the same error.
- `mydata()\[row,col\] \<\<- isolate(DT::coerceValue(value, mydata()\[row,col\]))` still the same error.
- transform my reactive dataframe into a non reactive dataframe i get : `"Error in \<-: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"`.
  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try `dat <- mydata(); dat[row, col] <- value; mydata(dat)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works i was sure it wasn't that difficult but i was stocked i didn't think of redefine the dataframe. Do you know why it didn't accept the previous coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a `reactiveVal`ue, say `reacval`, you have to do `val <- reacval()`. And to change it you have to do `reacval(newval)`. So here you can do:

```r
dat <- mydata()
dat[row, col] <- value
mydata(dat)
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you for the answer and sorry for my late response